# Как изменить размер столбца Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-grid

```
grid_center.ColumnDefinitions[3].Width.Value = 0;

<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="grid_center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
       //изменить размер этого столбца
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" Name="grig_col_200"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: А в чём проблема? У вас же написано первой строчкой.

Comment: Только индекс наверное неправильный, надо 2, нумерация-то от 0.

Comment: невозможно присвоить - доступ только для чтения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
grid_center.ColumnDefinitions[2].Width = new GridLength(0);
```

или просто

```
grig_col_200.Width = new GridLength(0);
```